# Is autopsy allowed in Islam?

Tags: fiqh, death

What does Islam command with respect to conducting an autopsy in case of suspicious death? Is it allowed to alter the body after one's death? Or do we leave the truth with Allah and allow him to take action on the culprit (if any) on Judgement Day?

Comment: I think you should define suspicious death first. But let's say the fiqh view is that only a necessity may make it permissible to do an autopsy on the body of a Muslim.

Comment: related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60137/can-graves-be-exhumed

Comment: Thank you @SpiderRico for the link but an autopsy can be performed even before 'burial of the body' into the grave.